# How to Filter foreign key related models using datetime range

Tags: django, datetime, django-models

I'm trying to create a reservation system and I want to query all available tables. So, what I did is as follows,

```
...
date_time = request.data.get('date_time')
date_time = datetime.strptime(date_time, '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
num_of_attendees = request.data.get('num_of_attendees')

tables = Table.objects.filter(~Q(
    tablereservation__date_time__range=[date_time, date_time + timedelta(hours=2)]), 
    num_of_chairs__gte=num_of_attendees
)
...
```

But it returns all the table objects.

My models,

```
class Table(models.Model):
    """ Holds table details """

    num_of_chairs = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class TableReservation(models.Model):
    """ Holds table reservation details """

    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self.table, self.user)
```

But I want is to get only the table objects that aren't reserved in the given date-time range. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

~Q is negation of Q expression.
I.E. ~Q is `NOT Q`

Are you sure you want ~Q?

Also, the issue is likely due to how `__range` interacts with `DateTimeField`.
See the documentation here:
[Range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#range) (I just ran into this issue yesterday, the issue will cause your query to always be empty on the final day of the range which your query is *always* for the final day of the range!)

You could try:

```
start_time = date_time

end_time = date_time + timedelta(hours=2)

tables = Table.objects.filter(
    tablereservation__date_time__gte=start_time, tablereservation__date_time__lte=end_time).filter(num_of_chairs__gte=num_of_attendees)
```

Comment: `~Q` Yeah, I want the tables that are free. I guessed that too. Anyway, I solved the issue by searching for free slots one by one for each table. Which isn't a good approach :(

Comment: Try my solution without the `__range` but instead replace `__range` with `__gte` and `__lte` that should be better than a "one by one" approach :)